# How to sort List of Objects, keeping original order if equal?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I want to sort a list of persons by age. If age is equal, I want to preserve the original order, independent of all other fields.

Example source:

```
persons: [{name=a, age=30}, {name=b, age=30}, {name=c, age=12}, {name=d, age = 30}]
```

Desired result:

```
persons: [{name=c, age=12}, {name=a, age=30}, {name=b, age=30}, {name=d, age = 30}]
```

Most important: as person A, B and D are considered to be equal, they are sorted at the bottom, BUT preserving their original order.

Question: is this behavior guaranteed with the following comparator?

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    //many more properties
}

Comparator<Person> comparator = Comparator.comparing(person -> person.getAge());
Collections.sort(persons, comparator);
```

Comment: So in short, the answer is: YES.

Comment: Take a look at sort() method, it preserves natural ordering.

Comment: If two objects are equal, then logically, the order is irrelevant, is it not ?